# Value Error:Setting an array element with sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, sparse-matrix

```
def get_column_normalized_matrix(A):
    d=sp.csr_matrix.get_shape(A)[0]           
    Q=mat.zeros((d,d))
    V=mat.zeros((1,d))
    sp.csr_matrix.sum(A,axis=0,dtype='int',out=V)
    for i in range(0,d):
        if V[0,i]!=0:
            Q[:,i]=sc.divide(A[:,i],V[0,i])
    return Q
```

Input A is an adjacency matrix of sparse format.I am getting the above as error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in get_column_normalized_matrix
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: You might as well paste the stack trace here instead of using an image.

Comment: Look at `sc.divide(...)`.  What is it?  Is it an array that will fit in `Q[:,i]`?  It might help if you also demonstrate this action with a dense array, e.g. `A.A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are trying to assign a sparse matrix into a dense one. This is not done automatically. It is rather simple to fix, though, by turning the sparse matrix into a dense one, using `.todense()`:

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
import numpy.matlib as mat
import scipy as sc

def get_column_normalized_matrix(A):
    d=sp.csr_matrix.get_shape(A)[0]
    Q=mat.zeros((d,d))
    V=mat.zeros((1,d))
    sp.csr_matrix.sum(A,axis=0,dtype='int',out=V)
    for i in range(0,d):
        if V[0,i]!=0:
            # Explicitly turn the sparse matrix into a dense one:
            Q[:,i]=sc.divide(A[:,i],V[0,i]).todense() 
    return Q
```

If you instead want the output to be sparse, then you have to ensure that your output matrix `Q` is sparse to begin with. That can be achieved as follows:

```
def get_column_normalized_matrix(A):
    d=sp.csr_matrix.get_shape(A)[0]
    Q=sp.csr_matrix(A) # Create sparse output matrix
    V=mat.zeros((1,d))
    sp.csr_matrix.sum(A,axis=0,dtype='int',out=V)
    for i in range(0,d):
        if V[0,i]!=0:
            # Update sparse matrix
            Q[:,i]=sc.divide(A[:,i],V[0,i]) 
    return Q
```

As can be seen, `Q` is created as a copy of `A`. This makes the same element being non zero in both matrices, which ensures efficient updating, since no new elements will be added.

Comment: But I want Q to be a sparse matrix too.So should I then again convert Q to sparse format in the next step?Wont it be very inefficient and slow for large matrices?

Comment: You defined `Q` as dense.  Trying to put sparse rows into it, even it worked, won't make it sparse.

Comment: But i had to initialize Q to a zero matrix.Since there is no sparse notation for it so I had to initialize it to a dense matrix.

Comment: @debmalyasarkar I have added a solution that makes `Q` a sparse matrix. Hopefully that is what you are hoping for.

Comment: Oh yes.Thats what I was hoping for.Thanks a lot!